# Change select to a previous date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have basic knowledge of SQL and have a question:

I am trying to select data from a time series (date and windspeed). I want to select the original wind speed value if it lies between hours 7 and 21. If the hour is outside this range I would like to assign the wind speed to the previous wind speed at hour 21. There is also a concern that there is the occasional point where hour 21 does not exist and would like to assign the windspeed as hour 20... 19 etc until it finds the next available hour.

```
SELECT 
    date,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(HH,date) < 7 OR DATEPART(HH,date) > 21  
    THEN '<WIND SPEED AT HOUR 21> ELSE <WIND SPEED> END AS ModifiedWindspeed 
    ,WindSpeed, winddirection
from TerrainCorrectedHourlyWind w
```

This might make things clearer. If the hour is in the specified range, select windspeed. If not then select the wind speed from the prior day at 21 hours.

Comment: So....., What is your question here?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Check out the guidelines for asking questions http://stackoverflow.com/faq.  In short, sample data, expected results, and attempts at queries always improve a question.

Comment: `DATEPART` doesn't exist in [tag:mysql]. Is this really [tag:sql-server]?

Answer (score 0):

Though you've tagged the question [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), I'm guessing this is actually SQL Server because of the `DATEPART()` function used. Try the following, which uses an `OUTER APPLY` to get your alternate value:

```
SELECT Date
     , CASE
           WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, Date)BETWEEN 7 AND 21 THEN w.WindSpeed
           ELSE m.WindSpeed
       END AS ModifiedWindSpeed
     , w.WindSpeed
     , w.WindDirection
  FROM TerrainCorrectedHourlyWind AS w
       OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 WindSpeed
                       FROM TerrainCorrectedHourlyWind
                   WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, Date)BETWEEN 7 AND 21
                       AND Date < w.Date
                   ORDER BY Date DESC)AS m;
```

Just to explain what this is doing--the `OUTER APPLY` will get the single most recent record (`TOP 1` and `ORDER BY Date DESC`) for dates prior to the record in question (`Date < w.Date`) as well as within the hours specified. The `CASE` near the top chooses whether to use the current value or this alternate one based on the hour.